# how to get rid of repeating GET http request?

Tags: python, server

so I have been coding stuff in socket programming (in python) for sometime. I created a simple server that does really nothing importent, but then I have noticed it keeps showing errors, and not only when running this server but when running other ones.
When checking for the GET messages sent to socket 80 on my computer from browser, I have found that there where two GET messages - one is the desired one, but the other has nothing to do with my code or browser request. how do I get rid of the other unwanted one?
the two GET requests:

```
GET /fd4 HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="102", "Google Chrome";v="102"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: he-IL,he;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Networks/hed/server_to_fix_problem.py", line 29, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Networks/hed/server_to_fix_problem.py", line 25, in main
    handle_client_G(client_socket)
GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
  File "C:/Networks/hed/server_to_fix_problem.py", line 13, in handle_client_G
    number_to_return = int(URL[-1]) + 1
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'o'
Host: 127.0.0.1
Connection: keep-alive
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="102", "Google Chrome";v="102"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Accept: image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: image
Referer: http://127.0.0.1/fd4
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: he-IL,he;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

so the first request is the one I want, but then there another one which I have not asked for!

```
import socket


def handle_client(client_socket):
    client_request = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
    URL = ""
    for i in client_request[5::]:
        if i != " ":
            URL += i
        else:
            break
    print(client_request)
    number_to_return = int(URL[-1]) + 1
    client_socket.send(str(number_to_return).encode())
    client_socket.close()


def main():
    server_socket = socket.socket()
    server_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", 80))
    server_socket.listen()

    while True:
        client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        handle_client(client_socket)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the request:

```
http://127.0.0.1:80/5
```

Comment: Show us your server code and client code. It's impossible to debug anything without code. See [mcve].

Comment: Most browsers will request the favicon, you cannot do much about it.

Comment: @bereal it never did, till recently